# Match Specific Column and Merge [ Different Length DF]

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am new to R and still learning.

I have two `data.frames`, `df` and `df1`.

```
page <- c("ABC", "DDD", "DSD")
freq <- c(1,33,555)
df <- data.frame(page, freq)

df1 <- data.frame(page = c("ABC", "DDD", "DSD", "SDSD", "vEf", "DDD"),
 URL = c("fakeurl1", "fakeurl2", "fakeurl3", "fakeurl4", "fakeurl5", "fakeurl6"))
```

I want to merge URL with df where take only the first URL that appeared as you can see that `df1` has multiple entries for same `page`.

I'd appreciate if someone can come with `base`, `dplyr` and `data.table` solution for this.

Comment: Do you mean that in page column, the DDD must be merged by first entry against it in `URL` ?

Comment: @RanaUsman yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

**R base Solution**

```
pagenondupe <- df1[!duplicated(df1$page, fromLast = F), ]
dfx <- merge(df, pagenondupe[,c("page", "URL")], by = "page", all.x = TRUE)
```

I am taking first non dupes from df1. If you have date, you can order it by date, and then merge.

In case you want to pull URL from last entry of non dupe, you can change `fromLast = T`

**Result**

```
 page freq      URL
  ABC    1 fakeurl1
  DDD   33 fakeurl2
  DSD  555 fakeurl3
```

**Dplyr**

```
df1 %>% 
group_by(page) %>% 
filter(row_number(URL) == 1) %>% 
inner_join(df, df1, by = "page")
```

**Result**

```
#page  URL       freq
#<chr> <fct>    <dbl>
#ABC   fakeurl1    1.
#DDD   fakeurl2   33.
#DSD   fakeurl3  555.
```

Comment: Default arguments happen to work here (for fromLast, by, all.x): `merge(df, df1[!duplicated(df1$page),])`, though I think it is better to be explicit as you have done.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for mentioning, I mentioned it, just in case if he needs to pull the url from last entry. Answer updated.

Comment: @Rana Dplyr has a `distinct` function that may work instead of your group_by + filter... something like `inner_join(distinct(df1, page, .keep_all = TRUE), df)`